# Adobe DTM - Accordion link click tracking

Tags: javascript, adobe, dtmf

I have a accordion link with plus symbol. When the user clicks on the plus symbol, then the accordion will expand .

Can anyone help me out how to get the text of the accordion using the Event based rule in adobe DTM.

Note: On click of Accordion symbol, the page will not load. It stays on the same page only accordion exapands.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via an event-based load rule.

Depending on how your element is embedded in the code, you need to address it.

For instance, if it is a class, you need to address it via `.class_name`.

As you are using DTM, I assume that you are using Adobe Analytics. Therefore, you need to create an eVar to which the value of the Accordion click is passed.

Furthermore, you need to set a custom code, which tells Adobe to write this value into the eVar.

This could be an example:

```
var label = $(this).attr("id");

_satellite.setVar("Label",label);

return true;
```

This code tells Adobe to get the attribute `id` and pass its value into the variable label.

As the last step, you need to map the evar to `%Label%` that the `name` of the part of the Accordion is passed to AA.

Good luck :)